# My WCF service installed as part of the Windows services stops - How to start it from my client without using a Timer?

Tags: c#, service, instance

I am now able to instantiate multiple times a same Windows service I have created.
I do manage to install individual instances using "InstallUtil.exe /servicename=TestX".
Meaning that each instance appears listed in my Windows services as it should (see [Service instance test1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1hjY.jpg)), but remains stopped.

I have seen in many threads that people use a Timer to automatically re-launch a service. Is that really necessary?
Is it ok to simply restart it from aclient app using a "ServiceController", which I have tried but without success.

Using the latter approach, I get an error though, saying the Pipe End point cannot be found on my local machine.
I am not sure this is actually related to my problem, but do I need to set a different endpoint for each newly created instance of my service?

Here is what I have done to allow multiple instantiations of the service:

```
namespace MyService.Service
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class MyServiceInstaller : Installer
    {
        public MyServiceInstaller()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Override Install/Uninstall to allow to run various instances of the same Service
        // Install via CMD from running from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319:
        //    InstallUtil.exe /servicename=test2 Path\bin\Debug\MyService.Service.exe: 
        public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
        {
            RetrieveServiceName();
            base.Install(stateSaver);
        }

        // To uninstall:
        //   InstallUtil.exe -u /servicename=test2 Path\bin\Debug\MyService.Service.exe: 
        public override void Uninstall(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
        {
            RetrieveServiceName();
            base.Uninstall(savedState);
        }

        // Set up name of each service instance
        private void RetrieveServiceName()
        {
            var serviceName = Context.Parameters["servicename"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceName))
            {
                this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName = serviceName;
                this.serviceInstaller1.DisplayName = serviceName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is from the App.config (which I believe is not relevant to my problem, but please let me know if I am doing something wrong here):

```
<services>
      <!-- This section is optional with the new configuration model introduced in .NET framework 4.0 -->
      <service name="MyService.Service.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/My.Service/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

        <!-- This endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host -->
        <endpoint address="MyServiceAddr" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="MyService.ServiceContract.IMyService"/>

        <!-- The mex endpoint is exposed at http://localhost:9000/MyService.Service/service/mex -->
        <endpoint address="MyServiceAddr/mex" binding="mexNamedPipeBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

      </service>
    </services>
```

Here is what my Proxy Constructor does:

```
private MyServiceProxy(string serviceName)
{
  var ctx = new InstanceContext(MyServiceCallbackProxy.Instance);

  var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
  var channelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IMyServiceService>(ctx, binding,
     new EndpointAddress(Constants.ServiceBaseAddress + serviceName));

   // Create channel to a specified endpoint
    _channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
 }
```

Finally, I have tried to start my service from my client (using a "ServiceController") as per [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/363/how-to-start-stop-and-verify-if-a-service-exists-with-c-in-winforms).
Note that the service gets found, but restarting/using it is another matter. 
Here is my actual Client code:

```
...
static bool serviceExists(string ServiceName)
{
 return ServiceController.GetServices().Any(serviceController =>   serviceController.ServiceName.Equals(ServiceName));
}
static void startService(string ServiceName)
{
 ServiceController sc = new ServiceController();
 sc.ServiceName = ServiceName;

 Console.WriteLine("The {0} service status is currently set to {1}", ServiceName, sc.Status.ToString());

 if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
 {
  // Start the service if the current status is stopped.
  Console.WriteLine("Starting the {0} service ...", ServiceName);
  try
  {
   // Start the service, and wait until its status is "Running".
   sc.Start();
   sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);

   // Display the current service status.
   Console.WriteLine("The {0} service status is now set to {1}.", ServiceName, sc.Status.ToString());
   }
   catch (InvalidOperationException e)
   {
    Console.WriteLine("Could not start the {0} service.", ServiceName);
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
   }
  }
  else
  {
   Console.WriteLine("Service {0} already running.", ServiceName);
  }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
 if (serviceExists("test1"))
 {
  Console.WriteLine("Service exists");
 }
 else
 {
  Console.WriteLine("Service doesn't exists");
 }

 startService("test1");

 // Connect to Proxy in order to run multiple APIs in parallel
 MyServiceProxy ServiceInst = MyServiceProxy.Instance("test1");
 …
```

The service Host is started this way:

```
public MyServiceWindowsService(sting serviceName)
{
  InitializeComponent();

  // Name the service
  ServiceName = serviceName;
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
  StartServiceHost();
}

private void StartServiceHost()
{
 // Stop the service before starting the service
 StopServiceHost();
 ServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));

 // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start listening for messages
 ServiceHost.Open();
}
```

And the main is doing:

```
public static void Main(string[] argsIn)
{
  ServiceBase[] servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
  {
    new MyServiceWindowsService(argsIn[0]),
  };
...
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask], [tour] and [mcve] to improve your questions chances of getting help

Comment: Please, show us your code and maybe we can help you

Comment: Without code no one can tell the problem you are having, but what do you mean by saying that you are able to instantiate a service? If this means that you are able to install the service, then ok, please remember that during installation hardly any validation about your code/service is done. Also from your error message it looks more like a tcp/connection binding issue rather than a service related one.

Comment: By instantiating, I mean instantiating. This is what "InstallUtil.exe /servicename=TestX" will do. It will create an instance based on the input servicename "TestX". So the same service can be run multiple times in parallel.
When installing a service instance though, I am not sure whether my bindings have to be tight to these service names. If so, it could be why it is breaking?
Not sure showing code really matters here, but I can add some if you really think it will help.

Comment: The question is not quite clear because it mixes the topic of "Windows Services" (A Windows application running as a background task) and "WCF Services" (A Software component offering functionality that can be called by clients). That's two different things and while you can have a WCF Service run inside a Windows Service, the two are not really related. You need to make your question more clear.

Comment: Well, yes, I did create a WCF service, which then got installed as part of a the Windows services. How is that not clear or even relevant to my questions?
If I am doing something wrong, it would be nice to hear about it, rather than saying my question is unclear!?

Comment: Show the code which starts the WCF Service inside the Windows service. The error message "Pipe End point cannot be found" means that there is no WCF Service that registers itself to listen at the address "net.pipe://localhost/My.Service/" where the client tries to reach it.

Comment: Thanks @NineBerry. Are you referring to the Proxy constructor that creates the Channel and EndPoint?

Comment: @NineBerry - I have updated my question and added the piece of my Client that starts the service. Let me know if you need something else.

Comment: Again: You are not understanding the difference between a Windows Service and a WCF service. It is not enough to have a Windows service. You need to start the WCF service explicitly. You have only shown code where the client starts the Windows service. You need to show the code inside the service that starts the WCF service component. Or the problem is most likely that you don't have that. (Create an instance of the `ServiceHost` class and call its `Open()` method. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-a-managed-windows-service

Comment: Thanks. Yes I did something similar. Please check my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your client, the address of the `EndPoint` is constructed dynamically from the name of the Windows Service:

```
new EndpointAddress(Constants.ServiceBaseAddress + serviceName)
```

You also need to make the `ServiceHost` use this address in `StartServiceHost()`:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(Constants.ServiceBaseAddress + ServiceName);
ServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), uri);

ServiceHost.Open();
```

Comment: That throughs the following exception: System.ArgumentException: 'This collection already contains an address with scheme net.pipe.  
I added the following line to my config, but without success: <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

Comment: Remove the `baseAddresses` configuration from the app.config file.

Comment: Thanks, the service is back and running, but running my client is still throwing: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: 'There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/...

Comment: Client and server are not using the exact same URI then.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, by adding the removed baseAddress to the endpoint address in the service config file, the error goes away. I suppose this bas address has to be defined elsewhere?

Comment: It's very difficult to answer your questions because a lot of your code is still missing. This would all be easier if you provided a [mcve]

Comment: thank you for your great support. It is a bit hard as it is part of a huge project. I could try to extract all service stuffs into simplified projects, but tricky. Either way, I'll keep on digging. I think your answers are pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Now removed the Main args and breaks again. Could it be because setting the URI on the service side does not actually set the endpoint address (as each newly install instance of my service should probably use a different endpoint)?

Comment: So, I thing the problem is because my service name provided to the installer is not the same as the one provided to the actual Windows service. Not sure how to do that though.

Comment: Awesome, very helpful, thanks. Now I am finally able to instantiate the service by name. Remaining is to get multiple instances to work simultaneously. I think I still have a problem with my creation of endpoint. Should create a new endpoint for each instance as they cannot share the same one. Will let you know what I find :-)

Comment: Mmmh, this is breaking: _ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MyService), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), ServiceName);_
I thought I did not need it anyway when using: _new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), uri);_
But either way, my new EndPoint does not work, when used by the proxy

Comment: Ok, I did it this way instead. Not breaking anymore, but does not seem to be the solution as Endpoints between Service and Proxy are still not matching: _ServiceHost.Description.Endpoints[0].Address = new EndpointAddress(uri);
            ServiceHost.Description.Endpoints[0].ListenUri = uri;_

Comment: I have created a new thread about the last bit of the Puzzle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55636837/finding-my-wcf-service-name-installed-as-a-windows-service-from-my-service-cla). Seems to still be a problem around the ServiceName to be passed from the installer to the actual service.